# Remove a specific character from php array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have this array i want remove

```
array (

        [79] => 0.0
        [80] => 0.0
        [81] => 0.0
        [82] => 0.0
        [83] => 0.0
        [84] => 0.0
        [85] => 0.0
        [86] => 0.0
        [87] => 0.0
        [88] => 0.0
        [89] => 0.0
        [90] => 2.0
        [91] => 13.0
        [92] => 17.0
        [93] => 0.0
        [94] => 0.0
        [95] => 0.0
        [96] => 0.0
        [97] => 0.0
        [98] => 0.0
        [99] => 0.0
        [100] => 3.0

    )
```

i want remove 0.0 how can do it easily please Help me out 
i want do this with out using loop

Comment: Try `array_filter()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'array_filter' function from PHP to filter null, empty string or 0.0 values

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Benz answer above

But another option could be [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$remove = array(0.0);
$filtered = array_diff($source_array, $remove);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_zero($string) {
    $remove = array("0", "0.0");
    if (in_array($string, $remove)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

$clean_array = array_filter($your_array, "is_zero");
```

This will remove everything that is 0 or 0.0. Might be nicer to use a cast comparison (int/float) than checking for a string...

Review http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php for infoamtion on array_filter()

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following :

```
<?php

$array=array('0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','2.0','13.0','17.0','3.0');

function myFilter($string) {
  return strpos($string, '0.0') === false;
}

$newArray = array_filter($array, 'myFilter');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '<pre>';

?>
```